# Are Bioimpedance sensor different from Biopotentials sensors?

Tags: current, sensor, biopotential

I am building an portable health device , for which i am want ECG , GSR etc. then i came across 2 terms Bioimpedance and Biopotentials. Are these two same.
Also can any one say the applications of these ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A biopotential sensor is simply a voltage meter with skin-compatible electrodes. A bioimpedance sensor is an ohmmeter, typically an AC ohmmeter. That's all there's to it. You've already listed the applications: measurement of ECG, galvanic skin response, EKG, EEG, EOG, etc.

Usually an impedance meter already has a voltage meter built-in, so any bioimpedance sensor can be easily made to sense the open circuit voltage when the excitation current is turned off.

Comment: Can you name a IC for biopotential and for Bioimpedance. ie like AFE4300 it can be used for ECG but, can it be used for GSR too.

Comment: There's no "IC for it". You have to understand the range of physical parameters that you wish to measure, and base your design on it. Understand the physiology first, not last.